# Set default option for dropdown and assign value in VueJS

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, v-model, vue-reactivity

I have 2 dropdowns that are connected. You select a language in the first dropdown and a list of voices associated with that language will appear in the second dropdown.

I want to set a default value to load in the first dropdown when I first load the page because on load it's empty.

In the view, I've set `:value="language"` but this is returning `object Object` in the HTML markup. If I set it to `language.id` the voices stop appearing.

[image]

All I want to do is set "English" as the default option when the page loads and retrieve the correct voices for the selected language.

Also, is there a better way to populate the default voice for each language instead of `setdropdown()` because that will get really long if I have 10s of languages.

```
data() {
    return {
        selected: '',
        selectedVoice: '',
        languages: [{
                "id": 1,
                "name": "English",
                "voices": [
                    {
                        "id": "en-jenny",
                        "name": "Jenny"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "en-davis",
                        "name": "Davis"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "name": "Spanish",
                "voices": [
                    {
                        "id": "es-lupe",
                        "name": "Lupe"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "es-juan",
                        "name": "Juan"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "es-miguel",
                        "name": "Miguel"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
    }
},

methods: {
    setdropdown() {
        if (this.selected.name == 'English') this.selectedVoice = 'en-jenny'
        else if (this.selected.name == 'Spanish') this.selectedVoice = 'es-lupe'
    }
},
```

And this is the view.

```
<select v-model="selected" class="form-control" @change="setdropdown()">
    <option v-for="(language, index) of languages" :key="index" :value="language">{{ language.name }}</option>
</select>

<select v-model="selectedVoice" class="form-control">
    <option v-for="(voice, index) of selected.voices" :key="index" :value="voice.id">{{ voice.name }}</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this approach:

```
<script>
export default {
  data() {
      return {
          selected: 1,
          selectedVoice: 'en-jenny',
          languages: [{
                  "id": 1,
                  "name": "English",
                  "voices": [
                      {
                          "id": "en-jenny",
                          "name": "Jenny"
                      },
                      {
                          "id": "en-davis",
                          "name": "Davis"
                      }
                  ]
              },
              {
                  "id": 2,
                  "name": "Spanish",
                  "voices": [
                      {
                          "id": "es-lupe",
                          "name": "Lupe"
                      },
                      {
                          "id": "es-juan",
                          "name": "Juan"
                      },
                      {
                          "id": "es-miguel",
                          "name": "Miguel"
                      }
                  ]
              }
          ],
      }
  },
   
  computed: {
    selectedVoices() {
      let selectedLanguage = this.languages.find(language => language.id === this.selected);
      return typeof selectedLanguage.voices !== 'undefined' ? selectedLanguage.voices : [];
    }
  },
  
  methods: {
    setDefaultValue() {
      this.selectedVoice = this.selectedVoices[0].id;
    }
  }

 }
</script>

<template>
  <div>
    <select v-model="selected" class="form-control" @change="setDefaultValue">
        <option v-for="language in languages" :key="language.id" :value="language.id">{{ language.name }}</option>
    </select>

    <select v-model="selectedVoice" class="form-control">
        <option v-for="voice in selectedVoices" :key="voice.id" :value="voice.id">{{ voice.name }}</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</template>
```

Few comments:

1. I suggest you use `computed` instead of `method` for getting voices
2. You can set the default value in data or in `mounted` hook
3. Don't use `index` as `key`, this is not recommend and can have impact to performance, instead use some property of an iterated object

Comment: This sort of worked but it's not selecting a default voice when u choose a language and I'm getting an error in the console `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'voices')`

Comment: This totally works, much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `mounted()` [Lifecycle Hook](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/lifecycle.html)

```
mounted() { 
  this.selected = this.languages[0];  
  this.setVoice();
}
```

And for the `setVoice()`

```
 setVoice() {
     this.selectedVoice = this.selected.voices[0].id;
 }
```

```js
const App = {
  data() {
    return {
        selected: '',
        selectedVoice: '',
        languages: [{
                "id": 1,
                "name": "English",
                "voices": [
                    {
                        "id": "en-jenny",
                        "name": "Jenny"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "en-davis",
                        "name": "Davis"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "name": "Spanish",
                "voices": [
                    {
                        "id": "es-lupe",
                        "name": "Lupe"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "es-juan",
                        "name": "Juan"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "es-miguel",
                        "name": "Miguel"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
    }
},
mounted() { 
  this.selected = this.languages[0];  
  this.setVoice();
},
methods: {
    setVoice() {
        this.selectedVoice = this.selected.voices[0].id;
    }
 }
}

const app = Vue.createApp(App)
app.mount('#app')
```

```css
#app { line-height: 1.75; }
[v-cloak] { display: none; }
```

```html
<div id="app" v-cloak>
  <select v-model="selected" class="form-control" @change="setVoice()">
      <option v-for="(language, index) of languages" :key="index" :value="language">{{ language.name }}</option>
  </select>&nbsp;
  <select v-model="selectedVoice" class="form-control">
    <option v-for="(voice, index) of selected.voices" :key="index" :value="voice.id">{{ voice.name }}</option>
  </select>
</div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
```

Comment: This worked, thank you. Follow up question, what about `:value="language"` it's returning `[object Object]` in the markup. is this normal?

Comment: Yes, it's better to bind the `value` to `language.id` and use `computed properties` as in the accepted answer.